# Windows %appdata% has Apple Computer folder?

Tags: macos, windows-10

I noticed when I was adding some files and textures to my games the "Apple Computer" folder...
Picture of the folder

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

What is this folder? Why is it on my computer?

Comment: Answers to what question?

Answer (score 5):

Windows 10 does not come with an Apple Computer directory. However, if you install Apple product, for example, iTunes, the Apple Computer directory will be created. In here you can find backup files. Refer this link for more info: https://support.apple.com/en-hk/HT204215